# Attempting to create a table in R that shows the mean and sd for stock prices of companies in each sector

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

I have financial data (CleanStocks.csv) that include sectors, companies, and their stock prices. I needed to find out find how many companies were in each sector so I did `table(CleanStocks$Sector)` which gave me this:

```
Consumer Discretionary           Consumer Staples                     Energy 
                    55                         25                          6 
            Financials                Health Care                Industrials 
                    60                         35                         52 
Information Technology                  Materials                Real Estate 
                    39                         20                         27
```

Now I need to get `sd(CleanStocks$Price)` and `mean(CleanStock$Price)` for the companies in each of the sectors above into the table also and don't really know where to start, seems simple but I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tapply(CleanStocks$Price,CleanStocks$Sector,mean)
tapply(CleanStocks$Price,CleanStocks$Sector,sd)
```